# Kickstart Ubuntu 16.04 Post Install Chown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kickstart

#### chown command issue in kickstart installation

I'm trying to run a `chown myuser:myuser` at the end of the `%post` section in my `ks.cfg` file. Everything before the chown runs successfully.

#### ks.cfg

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone America/Denver
#Root password
rootpw --disabled
#Initial user
user myuser --fullname "" --iscrypted --password ##############################/
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use hard drive installation media
# harddrive --dir=/ks.cfg --partition=4005-3596
cdrom 
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5
#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx

%packages
@ ubuntu-server
openssh-server
build-essential

%post --log=/root/ks-post.log
exec < /dev/tty6 > /dev/tty6 2> /dev/tty6
chvt 6
#mount the cd (ISO in my case) to copy files from it
#since this is chrooted environment
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
# Make directories
echo "***Making Directories***"
mkdir -p /home/myuser/bcfiles
mkdir -p /home/myuser/bin
# Copy bcsetup files
echo "***Copying bcsetup Files***"
cp -r /mnt/postfiles/bcsetup /home/myuser/bin
cp -r /mnt/postfiles/bcsetup-dev /home/myuser/bin
# Copy bcfiles directory
echo "***Copying bcfiles Directory***"
cp -r /mnt/postfiles/bcfiles /home/myuser/
# Copy myuser Profile Configuration Files
echo "***Copying myuser Profile Configuration Files***"
cp -r /mnt/postfiles/.bash_logout /home/myuser/
cp -r /mnt/postfiles/.bashrc /home/myuser/
cp -r /mnt/postfiles/.profile /home/myuser/
# Applying permissions
echo "***Applying Permissions***"
chown myuser /home/myuser/.bashrc
```

#### ks.cfg test with --nochroot

```
%post --nochroot --log=/root/ks-post.log
# Make directories
echo "***Making Directories***"
mkdir -p /target/home/myuser/bcfiles
mkdir -p /target/home/myuser/bin
# Copy bcsetup files
echo "***Copying bcsetup Files***"
cp -r /cdrom/postfiles/bcsetup /target/home/myuser/bin
cp -r /cdrom/postfiles/bcsetup-dev /target/home/myuser/bin
# Copy bcfiles directory
echo "***Copying bcfiles Directory***"
cp -r /cdrom/postfiles/bcfiles /target/home/myuser/
# Copy myuser Profile Configuration Files
echo "***Copying myuser Profile Configuration Files***"
cp -r /cdrom/postfiles/.bash_logout /target/home/myuser/
cp -r /cdrom/postfiles/.bashrc /target/home/myuser/
cp -r /cdrom/postfiles/.profile /target/home/myuser/
# Applying permissions
echo "***Applying Permissions***"
chown myuser:myuser -R /target/home/myuser/
```

#### After the install `cat /var/log/installer/syslog | grep kickseed` shows:

```
kickseed: chown: unknown user myuser:myuser
```

#### Afterthoughts

I've tried several different routes so far. The same thing happens if I exclude `--nochroot` from `%post`. I've seen other ks.cfg configurations using `chown myuser.myuser` which hasn't worked either. Also attempted `chown` on individual files within `/home/myuser/`.


Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

#### Updates

`/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` both list `myuser`.
Output of `groups myuser`: `myuser : myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`

#### Thoughts

At this point in time I'm thinking moving the scripts outside of `/home/myuser/bin` and into `/usr/local/bin` where I won't need to rely on `chown`.

Comment: Ensure that the group and the user exists via `addgroup ...` and `adduser ...`.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to end the post with %end in order for anything after %post to work. I believe...
Most of my experience is with Red Hat, CentOS & Fedora. Here is a link to the Fedora documentation: [https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora//html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-postinstall.html](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora//html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-postinstall.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially opted to do Preseed+Kickstart as I believed there was more functionality. However, after using preseed only I was able to accomplish everything without issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this problem recently and as I see it is one of the first results when googling I'll share the solution with you:

You can see your user is listed in /etc/passwd, however, it is being created after the %post section is executed. So at the time the %post script is running your user has not been created yet. Check the logs in /var/log/installer and search for post